# Healthvault security exception after deployment

Tags: c#, healthvault

I am developing a HealthVault webapplication (VS2012/asp.net). 
It works fine on my localhost. 
A Healthvault webapplication needs a certificate (a PFX) in order to run. I made sure this pfx is in a separate directory on the server and that my web.config is pointing to the right certificate.

When i test the application on my deploymet environment (http://www.mydomain.nl/healthvaultapp/default.aspx), i get the Healthvault login, but after logging in, the security exception is thrown. 
Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something is coming do dawn to me: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3473a0c5-9f19-4132-8224-854864d7845f/systemsecuritysecurityexception-the-specified-certificate-does-not-have-a-private-key?forum=healthvault

the certificate MUST have a password. I am trying to create one now WITH a password.